# Redundant Conformance Error In ViewControllers that has UINavigationControllerDelegate after Importing an external library

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I import this library manually to my project folder

https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLTransitionAnimator

But the problem is that, once I import this library in my bridging header

```
#import "YSLTransitionAnimator.h"
#import "UIViewController+YSLTransition.h"
```

I got compile error message

> /Users/jay/ios/TestProject/TestProject/ProfilePictureSetupViewController.swift:11:60:
>   Redundant conformance of 'ProfilePictureSetupViewController' to
>   protocol 'UINavigationControllerDelegate'

I know that this  `#import "UIViewController+YSLTransition.h"` is the one that cause the error but I have no idea why

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the class `UIViewController` has been extended with the `YSLTransition`. And it also already conformed the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. So you needn't to conform the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` again in your `ProfilePictureSetupViewController` view controller (remove it will fix the error)